# How to make Disqus to work with url routing?

Tags: javascript, meteor, routes, polymer, disqus

**SOLVED**

I have a default Disqus code pasted on my site:

```
...

var disqus_config = function () {
this.page.url = PAGE_URL; // Replace PAGE_URL with your page's canonical URL variable
this.page.identifier = PAGE_IDENTIFIER; // Replace PAGE_IDENTIFIER with your page's unique identifier variable
};

...
```

And my site is using polymer routing ( I have one html file with `<section></section>` for each page )

And as a routing I have this:

```
...
      page('/contact', function() {
        app.route = 'contact';
        setFocus(app.route);
        ga('set', 'page', '/contact');
        ga('send', 'pageview');
    });

      page('/privacy_policy', function() {
        app.route = 'privacy_policy';
        setFocus(app.route);
        ga('set', 'page', '/privacy_policy');
        ga('send', 'pageview');
    });
...
```

for each page.

Disqus is not working properly, when I open the Disqus admin panel itis only showing me a link to my comment for {{baseurl}}.com url even though I left a comment from baseurl.com/page/

What should I put instead of:

```
this.page.url = PAGE_URL; 
this.page.identifier = PAGE_IDENTIFIER;
```

I can't figure out how to put `app.route = 'contact';` there, because  `this.page.url = app.route = 'contact';` structure doesn't make sense, and I can't put the direct link there since https:// - will open a comment in the code.

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED IT:**

To resolve this problem just replace

```
var disqus_config = function () {
this.page.url = PAGE_URL;
this.page.identifier = PAGE_IDENTIFIER; 
};
```

with

```
var disqus_config = function () {
this.page.url = 'https://www.YourSiteName.com/YourRoutePageName';
this.page.identifier = 'SomeUniqueIdGoesHere';
};
```

Notice the **https** there. If you don't use **https**, just put **http** instead

For more on this, read https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472098-javascript-configuration-variables