# Set up Disqus Multiple Canonical URL in Magento

Tags: javascript, php, magento, disqus

I'm trying to integrate Disqus on my test Magento website. I'm using NeoTheme Blog Extension however I disabled the built in comment section and change it to disqus.

The problem was the canonical url. I have a main category http://?????.com/news-and-media/ that has a sub category /blog and /news and others. The blog page can be access as http://????/.com/news-and-media/blog-content and http://????/.com/news-and-media/blog/blog-content, both display the same content. I tried to comment on each url however the comment is missing from the other page and vice versa.

This is my progress so far.

My phtml

```
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
<script>
var disqus_config = function () {
this.page.url = 'http://?????.com/news-and-media/';
this.page.identifier = 'blog';
};
(function() { // DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');
s.src = 'https://????-com.disqus.com/embed.js';
s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
(d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
})();
</script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
```

My local.xml

```
<neotheme_blog_post_index>
    <reference name="disquscomment">
        <block type="core/template" name="dcomment" template="disqus-comments.phtml" />
    </reference>        
</neotheme_blog_post_index>
```

Do you have solution for this canonical? I can't seemed to undesrtand the documentation and example.

https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472098-javascript-configuration-variables

[How to make Disqus to work with url routing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37285962/how-to-make-disqus-to-work-with-url-routing)

Comment: Have you set up your canonical in the back-end?

Comment: yes, i manually add it on the design layout xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fetch the rel canonical value using javascript and use it as your page identifier. I'm not sure if this works.

```
var canonical = "";
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("link");
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i ++) {
if (links[i].getAttribute("rel") === "canonical") {
    canonical = links[i].getAttribute("href")
}
}
var disqus_config = function () {
this.page.url = '';
this.page.identifier = canonical;
};
(function() { // DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
```

Check this link for reference. http://javascript.qahowto.com/Obtaining-canonical-url-using-JavaScript-javascript-url-5b420a